# select2: jQuery and multiple dropdowns with same class

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using [Select2 jQuery](https://select2.org/) v.4 with multiple dropdowns on a page, i.e. like the HTML of one below. All use `dropdown-anchor` as a class. (The `{{ ... }}` constructs are Twig, but aren't relevant here.)

```
<select name="region">
  <option value>All</option>
  {% for reg in regions %}
  <option value="{{ reg.term_id }}"{{ (reg.term_id == region) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{ reg.name }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
<div class="dropdown-anchor"></div>
```

I'm trying to adopt the older jQuery function (below) to work with multiple instances of `.dropdown-anchor`on the page.

How can I rewrite the function below to work with select2 v.4 and jQuery v.3?

```
$(function () {
  $('select').each(function() {
    var dropdownAnchor = $(this).next('.dropdown-anchor');
    $(this).select2({
      theme: 'classic',
      minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
      width: '100%',
      dropdownParent: dropdownAnchor
    });
  });
```

Using `console.log` on dropdownAnchor.length shows `ReferenceError: dropdownAnchor is not defined`

The console shows the error `Uncaught query function not defined for Select2 undefined` on `jquery.min.js`

[image]

Comment: The jQuery code you posted should work... But if the `select` and `.dropdown-anchor` are not wrapped with a `div`... And you have many of them. They're all siblings. It may be your issue. Try `.next(".dropdown-anchor)` instead of  `.siblings(".dropdown-anchor)`.

Comment: About the error, make sure you loaded the select2 plugin.

Comment: Arrggg... :(  Select2 wasn't loading. Now it is loading, but now I get `Uncaught query function not defined for Select2 undefined`.

Comment: console.log the `dropdownAnchor.length`... Should be `1`.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see that in the console; the error is on ` jquery.min.js`; console added above,

Comment: Comment out the whole select2 init block and retry the console.log.

Comment: No error, so the cause of the error must be in the select2 block.

Comment: And what is `dropdownAnchor.length` ?

Comment: ReferenceError: dropdownAnchor is not defined

Comment: That is the problem. ;) Try `.next()`.

Comment: .next has been in all along :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue... See [codePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ZEpmjZz)

Comment: Thanks for all your help! It's a puzzle. I'll keep working on it.